# SVG Width of a rotated (matrix) rectangle. Looks like width and height numbers are scaled

Tags: svg

I am trying to analyse data in a SVG file I exported from coreldraw.

It is actually a file with a regular black colored 40x40 rectangle AND also the same 40x40 rectangle rotated 10 degrees and colored in red.

If I look at the SVG contents , then I can nicely see my 40x40 black rectangle and the line under it is the red rotated one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<!-- Creator: CorelDRAW Home & Student X7 -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="100px" height="100px" version="1.0" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
viewBox="0 0 100 100"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css">
   <![CDATA[
    .str0 {stroke:black;stroke-width:0.2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round}
    .str1 {stroke:red;stroke-width:0.2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round}
    .fil0 {fill:none}
   ]]>
  </style>
 </defs>
 <g id="Layer_x0020_1">
  <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
  <rect class="fil0 str0" x="15" y="19" width="40" height="40"/>
  <rect class="fil0 str1" transform="matrix(0.881289 -0.155395 0.169522 0.961407 11.5017 22.5159)" width="44.6985" height="40.9736"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

But.....

The red rotated one has no X or Y parameter specified. I read through some docs and think that this means that they are by default 0

Both the black original rectangle and the red rotated version have exactly the same size , but the red one is rotated by 10degrees.

If I look at the width and height of the red rectangle, then I see a width of 44.6985 and height of 40.9736 and that makes no sense to me at all.

It is a rectangle, so its height and width should be exactly the same. Even if you rotate it. I do also know that the rectangle will use more horizontal and vertical pixels of rotated by 10 degrees, but even then it should be the same number.

This makes me think that these values got somehow scaled in a non uniform way, but I can't imagine how I should calculate the correct width and height based on this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grafical editors have sometimes quite obscure algorithms for what they consider optimizing. What CorelDraw did here was to exchange the square for a rectangle in a different place and with unequal side lenghts  44.6985 × 40.9736, and then apply a matrix that not only rotates and translates the rectangle, but also scales it non-uniformly back to a 40 × 40 square. Why? Ask Corel.

The matrix used by them is

```
matrix(0.881289 -0.155395 0.169522 0.961407 11.5017 22.5159)
```

and is equivalent to (computed with and rounded a bit from this [online tool](http://frederic-wang.fr/decomposition-of-2d-transform-matrices.html))

```
translate(11.5017 22.5159) rotate(-10) scale(0.894884 0.976238)
```

A (counter-clockwise!) rotation of the square around the same center would be written as

```
rotate(-10 33.3443 40.7508) //or
translate(-6.56971 6.40931) rotate(-10)
```

which is equivalent to

```
matrix(0.984807 -0.173648 0.173648 0.984807 -6.56971 6.40931)
```

You might contrast this with how [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) writes the same rotation. It writes out the rotation legibly, but moves the origin to somewhere else:

```
<rect x="7.41712" y="24.1711" width="40" height="40" transform="rotate(-10)" />
```